# Django CMS using 2 PlaceholderFields outside cms

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I want to add 2 PlaceholderFields to my custom model (I'm using DjangoCMS 3.0.3).

Here is my `models.py`:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    # other fields here
    preview = PlaceholderField('preview', related_name='entry_preview_set')
    content = PlaceholderField('content')
```

And this is my template:

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% load cms_tags %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>{{ entry.name }}</h1>
    </div>
    {% render_placeholder entry.preview %}
    {% render_placeholder entry.content %}
{% endblock %}
```

In forntend I can edit only `entry.content` placeholder, but `entry.preview` is not rendered.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Maybe this?:
`Since 3.0 placeholder content can only be modified from the frontend, and thus placeholderfields must not be present in any fieldsets, fields, form or other modeladmin fields definition attribute.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This situation is described in documentation at http://docs.django-cms.org/en/3.0.1/extending_cms/placeholders.html

> If you add a PlaceholderField to an existing model, you’ll be able to see the placeholder on the frontend editor only after saving each instance.

I need to save every model instance before using newly added placeholders.

Comment: Did you succeed to modify your PlaceholderField with a non admin user? I've tried it even after granting all access in auth permissions and still I get the same message "You don't have permission to modify this plugin"